# Stripe - Don't collapse address element by default

Tags: stripe-payments

When adding an address element to my stripe form, Only the 'Address Line 1' appears by default. Once the user starts typing in their address the rest of the fields are displayed. Is it possible to show all of the address element fields when the form is ready and not hide 'Address line 2', 'City', 'State', 'Zip', and 'Phone number' by default?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the only way to currently expand the address element fields is to set default values when creating the address element. It looks like passing default values for just `state` and `country` will render the remaining fields. The phone field will also be expanded as long as the 'always' value is specified in fields.phone.

You'd do something like this:

```
const addressElement = elements.create("address", {
  mode: "shipping",
  defaultValues: {
    address: {
      state: 'CA',
      country: 'US',
    },
  },
  fields: {
    phone: 'always',
  },
});
```

Comment: Thanks @LauraT, I noticed setting default values worked as well, but this skips field validation which is not something I want.